# Issue with Apache 2.2.34 using as Reverse Proxy to call service on BizTalk server 2016

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

We are having problem in using Apache 2.2.34 as a reverse proxy.

Scenario - Call from third party over internet hits apache in DMZ to call a service exposed by ESB - BizTalkServer 2016 [esbdev ] in MZ environment.

The SOAP is happening over DMZ URL followed by /miles.

We are able to receive the hit and forward it to ESB server however, the redirection is not working out and getting 500 as error response

Configuration in httpd.conf is given below. Appreciate if anyone can share their feedback on this problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:50000>
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyVerify none
ProxyPreserveHost Off
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
#RequestHeader set Host "esbdev.capital.com"
ProxyPass /miles https://esbdev.capital.com/ABC.WCFService/SILService.svc
ProxyPassReverse /miles     https://esbdev.capital.com/ABC.WCFService/SILService.svc
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: what happends if you add "ProxyRequests off" right above ProxyPass?